# Format of the result file isn't what I requested

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

December of last year, I was able to create fbx file with reality capture following [this instructions.](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/tutorials/create-3d-mesh-from-photos/)

several months passed and recently I tried creating fbx file again with exact same photos.

I have set the format as fbx as follow while creating new photoscene:

```
curl -v $BASE'photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene' 
-X 'POST' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer '$AUTH 
-d 'scenename=cottage' 
-d 'format=fbx'
-d 'scenetype=object'
```

The result was 3dp file, [which wasn't what I was expecting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkDdD.png)

I was able to download the file but can't open it. There may be ways to convert it to fbx but nature of the service I'm making doesn't have room for that.

What should I do fix this issue?

Comment: can you please share the `photosceneid`? the API have not changed, so need to check what went wrong

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves photosceneid is `7SIe2zdnG5tQXEEaizan1MsvC1ofoqMYheS90b1gSgI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our records, that scene was requested without the `format` parameter, resulting in the default `3dp` output. Please ensure the parameter is specified.